# RDLC Rectangle with tablix inside keep growing

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc, subreport, visual-studio-2019

I have a subreport containing a `rectangle` with inside a `tablix` that have dynamic number of rows. I used a rectangle as a container because I want my tablix to have a fixed maximum height so it can't push other objects down. unfortunately this doesn't work.

This is my SubReport, the `Rectangle`is selected in the picture and my `Tablix` is [colore]:

[image: Subreport]

This is an example of the rendered subreport with 2 rows only, everything is ok:
[image]

This is an example with more than 2 rows, the rectangle for some reason grows and everything get pushed down:

[image]

I tried with `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` both to `true` and `false` but nothing change.

How can I fix this ? I want my layout to always be like the secondo picture.